# SharePoint Push Notifications to Client Apps

Tags: sharepoint, push-notification, outlook, mpns

As a software developer, I want to write app ( whether that is a desktop app, a library, a web app, an Outlook AddIn, a mobile app ) that is notified about any changes at SharePoint.

These changes could be a file was added to a folder or library, or a file might be updated, deleted, a folder was added or deleted or renamed etc, etc

Is there a way for clients to register for certain push notifications so that the app does not have to do pulls every set time interval (i.e every 5 minutes or so) in order to update its UI.

If so, what versions of SharePoint support this?

After spending few hours researching this, all I keep finding is push notifications to windows phone like this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-configure-and-use-push-notifications-in-sharepoint-apps-for-windows

**UPDATE**

Targets are:

1. SharePoint 2010 and higher
2. Outlook 2010 and higher
3. App type: Outlook AddIn, so it is app running on a client (Outlook),
   not a SharePoint app
4. App is running on same network, not an external network
5. App has SharePoint permissions that are same as whatever permissions
   user has, nothing different than that

Answer (score 1):

If you app can receive emails, then all versions of SharePoint support list and library Alerts. An Alert can be triggered on adds and edits of documents and list items. Alerts can be sent almost immediately, or in on a schedule in summary form.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802949(v=office.14).aspx

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic info.  Would you mind elaborating a bit what do you mean by receiving emails?  I dont need email, I need notification so I can programatically process it, not to view it in my email box.  By process it, I mean, I need to ensure that whatever folders structure or items I am looking at in my app (Outlook AddIn) is uptodate at all times. 
 Also, is there an API to allow me to programmatically change the parameters in the screenshot you provided?

Comment: ... I am talking about ensuring that my libraries, folders, files, docsets, metadata, views show uptodated in my add-in.

Comment: You will need to tell me a bit more... SharePoint version, where you code/app will run (on the server, on a client on the same network, or external), what permissions you or your app will have to SharePoint, will the app be a SharePoint app, web part, etc.?

Comment: I am talking about SP2010 and higher.  The app is an Outlook Add-in (Outlook versions 2010 and higher), so it runs on PC.

Comment: I added update section to question above to provide the answers to your questions.  Much appreciate